# What does the Perfmon counter "Suboptimal plans/sec" actually measure?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, what does the Perfmon counter "Workload Group Stats:Suboptimal plans/sec" measure?

It's one of the [Resource Governor counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-workload-group-stats-object), so it's measured at the workload group (which you have whether you configure RG or not.)

I'm not asking what makes a good plan or a bad plan, but what specifically does that counter measure, and where do you go to find the exact corresponding plans? For example, I can't find anything in Extended Events that would seem to match to a query triggering the "Suboptimal plans/sec" counter.

Comment: I wonder if it's about the plan optimization level timing out before getting a great plan.

Comment: I was thinking it would be `StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="TimeOut"` but hard to say for sure!   That doesn't correlate well with the perfmon counter though.

Answer (score 7):

There are two items this counter tracks:

1. Timeout
2. Memory Limit Exceeded

The values can be found in the XML plan as Max has proposed in the comments. I can confirm it has been this way since at least SQL Server 2008.

Kudos to @Max Vernon and @Joe Obbish.

The <strike>MSDN BOL Technet</strike> [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-workload-group-stats-object) description isn't super helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Sean.  I've been looking at `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` and searching the plan cache for Timeout items, and saw the DMV not incrementing whilst the `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` is showing recently used timed-out queries.  Perhaps I'll put together an MCVE tomorrow to explore that.  Also, of note, that's happening on one of our EDW production instances running 2012 Enterprise.